# nullpointer on ListView (not using ListActivity)

Tags: android

I've created a layout in XML and it includes a ListView. I can use the ListView just find inside my `AsyncTask`. In `onCreate`, I did: `listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);`

And in onPostExecute of my AsyncTask, I did: `listView.setAdapter(new OfferAdapter(Main.this, offers));` THIS WORKS JUST FINE.

But if I try `listView.setDivider(null)` in `onCreate`, then the app crashes with a `nullpointer` there.

How am I supposed to grab hold of my `ListView` when I'm not using `ListActivity`?

Comment: post logs from logcat. is it the listview causing the NPE or the null divider..

Answer (score 0):

If `findViewById` is returning null, I'd make sure you are calling it after `setContentView`, and that you are using the correct ID.

Comment: I am doing it after `setContentView` and I've got the right id. Very strange... for whatever reason it's working fine now. I didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to set the divider in xml, ie:

```
android:divider="@drawable/icon".
```

If you want more control, verify that you are following this syntax in your activity:

```
public class DividerExampleActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setDivider(null);
    }
}
```

I've examined the ListView.java source code, and setting it to null should be fine.
Another option might be to make yourself a very thin, transparent divider in xml (say 0.5dp).